# How to implement user-customizable keyboard shortcuts (in javascript/on the web)

Tags: javascript, keyboard-shortcuts

The title says most of it. I'd like a javascript/html solution for how to make persistent, user-configurable keyboard shortcut listeners (plus any nice thoughts on how to actually persist the preferences if you have 'em).

It seems both straightforward and slightly tricky at the same time :)

Thanks!

Comment: I would look into the `keypress` event (probably on `document`, for listening to keyboard events on the whole page), and for storing the preferences you can use localStorage (not for sensitive data but fine for keyboard configuration) or a simple cookie if the settings aren't too complex.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow the user get shortcuts like "Control"+(...), you just have to capture the keys pressed, so check if "Control" is pressed with such keys pressed to do an action.

This is an simple and bad example of doing this:

```
var Pressed={
   CTRL:false,
   Spacebar:false
},Keyboard={ // an object containing Keyboard keys code
   CTRL:17,
   Spacebar:32
};
window.onkeydown=function(e){ // user started pressing an key (event)
   var Key=(e.keyCode||e.which||e.key); // capture key pressed from event
   if(Key==Keyboard.CTRL){ // CTRL is pressed
      Pressed.CTRL=true
      Pressed.Spacebar=false // CTRL has to be pressed before than Spacebar
   }else if(Key==Keyboard.Spacebar){ // Spacebar is pressed
      Pressed.Spacebar=true
   }
   if(Pressed.CTRL&&Pressed.Spacebar){ // Case CTRL+Spacebar are pressed
      e.preventDefault(); // prevent Opera from quitting from the page
      console.log("CTRL+Spacebar were pressed.")
   }
},
window.onkeyup=function(e){ // event when an key is released
   var Key=(e.keyCode||e.which||e.key); // capture key released from event
   if(Key==Keyboard.CTRL){ // CTRL is released
      Pressed.CTRL=false
   }else if(Key==Keyboard.Spacebar){ // Spacebar is released
      Pressed.Spacebar=false
   }
};
```

To update...

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

For demo purpose, I have just logged if `Alt`, `Ctrl` or `Shift` + 'Key' and if key is defined in shortcuts, then print `Special action` else 'Normal action'. Also I have disabled propagation of key events for inputs, but this section can be removed if not required.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/3s8y3h77/)

#### Code

```js
(function keyLogger() {
  var isCtrlPressed = false;
  var isAltPressed = false;
  var isShiftPressed = false;
  
  var shortcutKeys = [
    13, // Enter
    32, // Space
    37, // Left Arrow
    38, // Up Arrow
    39, // Right Arrow
    40, // Down Arrow
    90, // z
  ]

  function registerEvents() {
    document.onkeydown = function(event) {
      var keyCode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which;
      if (keyCode >= 16 && keyCode <= 18) {
        updateKeyFlags(keyCode, true);
      }

      if (isCtrlPressed || isAltPressed || isShiftPressed) {
        if (shortcutKeys.indexOf(keyCode) >= 0) {
          console.log("Special action");
        } else {
          console.log("Normal action");
        }
      }
    }

    document.onkeyup = function(event) {
      var keyCode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which;
      if (keyCode >= 16 && keyCode <= 18) {
        updateKeyFlags(keyCode, false);
      }
    }

    // To prevent logging from Inputs.
    // Can be removed if this action is required.
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i in inputs) {
      inputs[i].onkeyup = function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
      }
      inputs[i].onkeydown = function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
      }
    }
  }

  function updateKeyFlags(keyCode, flag) {
    switch (keyCode) {
      case 16:
        isShiftPressed = flag;
        break;
      case 17:
        isCtrlPressed = flag;
        break;
      case 18:
        isAltPressed = flag;
        break;
    }
  }

  registerEvents();
})();
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
</div>
```